# Errors when adding floats to Struct using ctypes

Tags: python, c#, structure, ctypes

I'm using ctypes to create a structure with floats. Later in the program this is used in C-code.
When testing my code only with shorts, the thing is running without a problem, but when switching one variable in the struct to double, I get an error.

**python-code**

```
from ctypes import  c_double, c_short, c_float, CDLL, byref, Structure, POINTER, c_ubyte, c_int,c_void_p, c_int64, cast

class HdrInfo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Vlo", c_short),
        ("Vhi", c_short),
        ("Vint", c_short),
        ("Vslo", c_float)
    ]

#filling up the structure
elems = (POINTER(HdrInfo) * NUMBER_OUT_FILES)()
simple_headers_out = cast(elems, POINTER(HdrInfo))
for key, setting in pheno_settings['out'].items():

        simple_headers_out[key].Vlo = 1
        simple_headers_out[key].Vhi = 2
        simple_headers_out[key].Vint = 3
        simple_headers_out[key].Vslo = 4.0
```

It result in the following error : Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
I guess this is just the same as a segmentation fault.
So if I switch Vint to c_short and set its value later on to 4, it works like a charm. Why it doesn't work with floats?

Comment: `Vint = 4.0` but `("Vint", c_short)` ? Wrong type i guess ?

Comment: you are right about this, only this was a typo in putting the code here. I have adapted my question. The error does still exist of course.

Comment: I tried your code (a bit simplified, without all the dicts), but this worked for me when I switched to c_float type. Can you copy the whole error ?

Comment: Currently the folowwing error is the only thing I see. Is there a way to increase the stacktrace when using those ctypes?
```Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)```

Comment: I have found a solution which I can't explain why it works. I have moved the Class definition of the Struct  to the same function as where I am filling it up. That does the trick. But why?

Comment: I get the following error now:  free(): invalid pointer

Comment: Why do you need to set *float*s? There are lots of related questions here. You are missing data (like the *C* structure), and how you use your data.
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details.